# ASP.Net API App - continual HTTP 502.3 errors

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-fabric

My team and I have been at this for 4 full days now, analyzing every log available to us, Azure Application Insights, you name it, we've analyzed it.  And we can not get down to the cause of this issue.

We have a customer who is integrated with our API to make search calls and they are complaining of intermittent but continual 502.3 Bad Gateway errors.

Here is the flow of our architecture:

All resources are in **Azure**.  The endpoint our customers call is a .NET Framework 4.7 Web App Service in Azure that acts as the stateless handler for all the API calls and responses.

This API app sends the calls to an Azure Service Fabric Cluster - that cluster load balances on the way in and distributes the API calls to our Search Service Application.  The Search Service Application then generates and ElasticSearch query from the API call, and sends that query to our ElasticSearch cluster.

ElasticSearch then sends the results back to Service Fabric, and the process reverses from there until the results are sent back to the customer from the API endpoint.

What may separate our process from a typical API is that our response payload can be relatively large, based on the search.  On average these last several days, the payload of a single response can be anywhere from 6MB to 12MB.  Our searches simply return a lot of data from ElasticSearch.  In any case, a normal search is typically executed and returned in 15 seconds or less.  As of right now, we have already increased our timeout window to 5 minutes just to try to handle what is happening and reduce timeout errors for the fact their searches are taking so long.  However, we increased the timeout via the following code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(s => {
   return new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300) };
 });
```

I've read in some places that you actually *have* to do this in the web.config file as opposed to here, or at least in addition to it.  Not sure if this is true?

So The customer who is getting the 502.3 errors have significantly increased the volumes they are sending us over the last week, but we believe we are fully scaled to be able to handle it.  They are still trying to put the issue on us, but after many days of research, I'm starting to wonder if the problem is actually on their side.  Could it be possible that *they* are not equipped to take the increased payload on *their* side.  Can it be that their integration architecture is not scaled enough to take the return payload from the increased volumes?  When we observe our resources usages (CPU/RAM/IO) on all of the above applications, they are all normal - all below 50%.  This also makes me wonder if this is on their side.

I know it's a bit of a subjective question, but I'm hoping for some insight from someone who may have experienced this before, but even more importantly, from someone who has experience with a .Net API app in Azure which return large datasets in it's responses.

Any code blocks of our API app, or screenshots from Application Insights are available to post upon request - just not sure what exactly anyone would want to see yet as I type this.

Comment: seems to me the number of hops in your logic is responsible to this error or, the size / delay to generate the response

Comment: How would we be able to control/reduce number of hops when this architecture is completely standard for what we're doing?  I don't believe the number of hops to be extraordinary in any shape or form, and we've had this architecture up in running like this for 3.5 years now with no issues.

Comment: I am not saying it's wrong. I believe it can be the reason as network is fragile and should not be trusted

Comment: If it was running fine before, and there were no major changes in your side, you should raise a ticket to support. PS: do not ignore the other two possible reasons I've mentioned (time to generate / size) of your response